# Fast way to calculate determinant for a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I have a block matrix

$$Q_{(n+m-1)\times(n+m-1)} = \begin{pmatrix} A & -J\\-J^t & B \end{pmatrix}$$

where

$$A_{(m-1)\times(m-1)} = n*I_{(m-1)\times(m-1)} \text{ and } B_{n\times n} = m*I_{n\times n}$$

where $I$ is identity matrix. $J$ is then $(m-1)\times n$ matrix with all entries $1$.

For example, when $m = 4, n = 2$ we have

$$Q_{5\times 5} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1\\ 0 & 2 & 0 & -1 & -1\\0&0&2&-1&-1\\-1&-1&-1&4&0\\-1&-1&-1&0&4\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer is  $n^{m-1}\cdot m^{n-1}$ but I don't know how to show that. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) the formulae for the determinant of block matrices under assumptions which are satisfied in your case, as $A$ is invertible, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in [wikipedia the page of determinat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) in section 3.3 on the Block matrices.

When $A$ is Invertible matrix, we have
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}A& B\\ C& D\end{pmatrix} = \det(A) \det(D - C A^{-1} B).
$$

When $D$ is invertible, a similar identity with $\det(D)$ factored out can be derived analogously,

$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}A& B\\ C& D\end{pmatrix} = \det(D) \det(A - B D^{-1} C).
$$
In this case 
\begin{align}
\det\begin{pmatrix}A & -J \\ -J^T & B \end{pmatrix}=
&
\det A \cdot \det\big( B-JA^{-1}J^T  \big)
\\
=
&
n^{m-1}\det
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 m & m-1 & \ldots & m-1 & m-1\\
m-1 & m & \ldots & m-1 & m-1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots & \vdots\\
 m-1 & m-1 & \ldots & m & m-1\\
 m-1 & m-1 & \ldots & m-1 & m\\
\end{array}
\right]_{n\times n}
\end{align}
Now, note that 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 m & \ldots & m-1 & \ldots  & m-1\\
m-1 &\ldots & m-1 & \ldots  & m-1\\
\vdots &   & \vdots & & \vdots\\
m-1    &   &   m    &  & m-1\\
\vdots &   & \vdots & & \vdots\\
 m-1 &\ldots & m-1 & \ldots & m-1\\
 m-1 &\ldots & m-1 & \ldots  & m\\
\end{array}
\right]_{n\times n}
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
\vdots\\
0\\
\vdots\\
1\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right] 
=
(m-1)
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
\vdots\\
0\\
\vdots\\
1\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
implies 
$$
\det
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 m & \ldots & m-1 & \ldots  & m-1\\
m-1 &\ldots & m-1 & \ldots  & m-1\\
\vdots &   & \vdots & & \vdots\\
m-1    &   &   m    &  & m-1\\
\vdots &   & \vdots & & \vdots\\
 m-1 &\ldots & m-1 & \ldots & m-1\\
 m-1 &\ldots & m-1 & \ldots  & m\\
\end{array}
\right]_{n\times n}
=
(m-1)^n
$$
and then
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}A & -J \\ -J^T & B \end{pmatrix}=n^{m-1}\cdot (m-1)^n
$$

Comment: I arrived there as well, I was thinking what can we say about $(m-1)*J+I$. I think using $eig((m-1)*J)$ and $eig((m-1)*J+I)$, and that $det = \prod_{i} \lambda_i$, we can arrive at correct result.

Comment: There are some mistakes in your answer though. $\det A = n^{m-1}$ and that $B-JAJ^{T} = B-\frac{1}{n}JJ^{T}$, but idea in general is correct.

Comment: @mezhang Feel free to correct any errors.